# Why is Ubuntu finding no bootable medium?

Tags: boot, virtualbox

My VMware  ubuntu OS is finding no bootable medium and therefore halting the VM, but all of the system and storage settings in the settings panel are greyed out, why does this happen? Also I use Windows 10 as my host OS

Answer (score 1):

Your settings are greyed out because your virtual machine is running.
Did you put in the installation file (.iso) in the sata-port?